# I can't use libx265 or hevc with ffmpeg in nginx

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264, libx265

`exec_push /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://10.254.20.186:1935/$app/$name  ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -g 25 -f flv rtmp://10.254.20.186/live/$name_hi;`

I can use this code in my nginx server. this is code running but dont run while write libx264 instead libx265.
The interesting thing is that I can run the following commands on my linux computer without problems.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v hevc -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output264tt.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v h264 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output264tt.mp4`

Comment: There is no official support for hevc in RTMP. Any tools that support it are technically breaking the standard.

Comment: Is this information correct? if possible, is there a source?

Comment: Of course its correct. I wouldn't type it if it was incorrect. Look at the [specification document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf). Section E.4.3.1

Comment: may I ask one more thing? this document only says h263 but I can use h264. Is there any chance of using rtmp in any other format than flv?

Comment: H264 is also called AVC (like h265 is also called HEVC). And no rtmp uses flv. No other options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and you have helped me a lot. okey, I can't use H265 with rtmp. So why can't I change the flv format in rtmp.

Comment: Rtmp just assumes FLV. There is nothing in RTMP to “change” to tell it to use something else. That setting simply doesn’t exist.

Comment: I don't want to take any more of your time, but I want to ask you one more question. can I convert the "H265" compressed video stream to the "h264" compressed video stream using ffmpeg? and redirect to the client?